# slurm salloc and how it get user login

Tags: ssh, slurm

Some theoretical question. I understand that the better way to know is to look at the code, but maybe I can do some cheat and just ask about it?

I wonder that after `salloc` user can log in to the node.

How does it work? Does `salloc` add user to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` or `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and after job completely delete the user?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue had to do with rules in `pam` like:

```
account    sufficient   pam_listfile.so item=user sense=allow file=some_file onerr=fail
```

As I understand it, `pam` looks to file with allowed users and get access only if user exists in this access_file